# Save user input string to variable on button click

Tags: java, pubnub

in my application the user will input a channel they want to subscribe to in an editable text field. Upon clicking the subscribe button, the variable that is placed in my method to subscribe the user should be updated to that of the users choice and then a toast will appear notifying the user that they are subscribed to this channel.

At the bottom, I get the string value that the user inputs in the EditText field, but I don't think I'm putting it in the right place. Can someone take a look at it and let me know what I'm doing wrong? Let me know if I wasn't clear or am missing something and I can try to explain better. Thanks!

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private Button channelSubscribeButton;
private EditText subscribeChannelEditText;

//Declare variable
String subscribeChannel = null;


//-------------------------Access PubNub API-------------------------//
Pubnub pubnub = new Pubnub("pub-c-940c4776-36ff-425f-9677-f1c904a9d57b", "sub-c-cf42b292-a8bf-11e4-85d5-0619f8945a4f");


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    channelSubscribeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subscribe_button);
    subscribeChannelEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.channel_name);



    //-------------------------Subscribe to a Channel to Receive Messages-------------------------//



    try {
//THIS IS WHERE I AM INPUTTING THE VARIABLE THAT CONTAINS THE USER INPUTTED TEXT//
//I AM GETTING ERROR THAT SAYS IT CAN'T RESOLVE THE SYMBOL 'subscribeChannel'//

        pubnub.subscribe(subscribeChannel, new Callback() {

                    @Override
                    public void connectCallback(String channel, Object message) {
                        Log.d("PUBNUB", "SUBSCRIBE : CONNECT on channel:" + channel
                                + " : " + message.getClass() + " : "
                                + message.toString());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void disconnectCallback(String channel, Object message) {
                        Log.d("PUBNUB", "SUBSCRIBE : DISCONNECT on channel:" + channel
                                + " : " + message.getClass() + " : "
                                + message.toString());
                    }

                    public void reconnectCallback(String channel, Object message) {
                        Log.d("PUBNUB", "SUBSCRIBE : RECONNECT on channel:" + channel
                                + " : " + message.getClass() + " : "
                                + message.toString());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void successCallback(String channel, Object message) {
                        Log.d("PUBNUB", "SUBSCRIBE : " + channel + " : "
                                + message.getClass() + " : " + message.toString());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void errorCallback(String channel, PubnubError error) {
                        Log.d("PUBNUB", "SUBSCRIBE : ERROR on channel " + channel
                                + " : " + error.toString());
                    }
                }
        );
    } catch (PubnubException e) {
        Log.d("PUBNUB", e.toString());
    }

public void onChannelButtonClick(View view) {

    subscribeChannel = String.valueOf(subscribeChannelEditText.getText());

    String yourSubscribeChannel = "Subscribed to the " + subscribeChannel + " Channel";

    Toast.makeText(this, yourSubscribeChannel, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return subscribeChannel;
}
```

Comment: can you please post the logcat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your subscribeChannel variable is only visible within the scope of your onChannelButtonClick method. Declare it outside along with your instance variables.

```
public void onChannelButtonClick(View view) {    
    //here you set it and then it's lost.
    String subscribeChannel = String.valueOf(subscribeChannelEditText.getText());    
    String yourSubscribeChannel = "Subscribed to the " + subscribeChannel + " Channel";    
    Toast.makeText(this, yourSubscribeChannel, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
}
```

Instead do:

```
//declare it.
String subscribeChannel = null;
```

And then on your method assign the value.

```
public void onChannelButtonClick(View view) {    
    //assign it.
    subscribeChannel = String.valueOf(subscribeChannelEditText.getText());    
    String yourSubscribeChannel = "Subscribed to the " + subscribeChannel + " Channel";    
    Toast.makeText(this, yourSubscribeChannel, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!

I've edited the code to reflect your advisement, but my app is still crashing. But now, instead of crashing when I press the button, it won't even open.